# How to Get an Approximate Row in SQL

Tags: mysql

I want to get a row with the closest value to the input value among the stored row data.  How do I write a query?

```
ex)

index  name   score
--------------------
  1    Jun     30
  2    Ann    -16
  3    Mick    54
  4    Kki     21
 ...

input : 25
--> result : 4, Kki, 21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether `ex)` is stray typing, or the name of your table. Let's assume your table is called `t`, and your input is stored as `@input=25`.

```
set @input=cast(25 as signed);

Select t.index, t.name, t.score
from
  (select 
    index
  , abs(score - @input)
  from t
  order by 2
  limit 1) as sq 
inner join t using (index);
```

... if your table is a temporary table, it will give you an error about not being able to open the same table twice. In that case, you might need the following code.

```
create temporary table t2 like t;
insert into t2 
  select * from t;
```

... and you'd replace one of the two references to `t` with `t2`. If it is a permanent table, you shouldn't have to do that.

That aside, the code works by first finding the row for which the absolute difference between the row's value and your reference value is smallest. (We sort, which by default sorts from smallest to largest, and limit the rows returned to a single result.) This single row, from the subquery, is joined back to our table on the index.